# Chrome Remote Debugger Get JS Input Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to use the Node module "chrome-remote-interface" to connecto to Google Chrome debug port.

I'm able to connect and intercept all the debugger messages, and I can see my function on the Websocket Message and the returned value, but I'm not able to get the input params of the function.

Example:

```
{
    "callFrameId": "{\"ordinal\":0,\"injectedScriptId\":3}",
    "functionName": "capitalizeString",
    "functionLocation": {
        "scriptId": "74",
        "lineNumber": 25,
        "columnNumber": 25
    },
    "location": {
        "scriptId": "74",
        "lineNumber": 27,
        "columnNumber": 23
    },
    "url": "file:///test.html",
    "scopeChain": [
        {
            "type": "local",
            "object": {
                "type": "object",
                "className": "Object",
                "description": "Object",
                "objectId": "{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":55}"
            },
            "name": "capitalizeString",
            "startLocation": {
                "scriptId": "74",
                "lineNumber": 25,
                "columnNumber": 25
            },
            "endLocation": {
                "scriptId": "74",
                "lineNumber": 28,
                "columnNumber": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "global",
            "object": {
                "type": "object",
                "className": "Window",
                "description": "Window",
                "objectId": "{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":56}"
            }
        }
    ],
    "this": {
        "type": "object",
        "className": "Window",
        "description": "Window",
        "objectId": "{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":57}"
    },
    "returnValue": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "ANOMBRE"
    }
}
```

Anybody knows how the get the input values of the JS function using "chrome-remote-interface"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I have to use "Runtime.getProperties" to get a Promise with the value of the field.